# How to fetch MAX rank using case statement mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, ranking

Already checked solutions related to my question but didn't get what I want to achieve
Here is my table structure (for ex. where table name is `tbl_rank`)

```
name      rank
apple       10
banana       2
grapes       5
orange       1
chiku        0
pineapple    0
```

Now What I want as result is that the elements with `0` rank should be given the max rank and all the elements should appear in descending order of their rank (actually creating a new column as new_rank),
This is the desired result

```
name      rank new_rank
apple       10       10
chiku        0       10
pineapple    0       10
grapes       5        5
banana       2        2
orange       1        1
```

To get the above result I am using this query

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN rank=0 THEN MAX(rank) ELSE rank END) as new_rank
FROM `tbl_rank` ORDER BY new_rank DESC
```

but all I am getting is only one row as result of the above query

[image]

No idea where I am doing wrong or why its returning only one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.*, (CASE WHEN A.rank = 0 THEN B.rank ELSE A.rank END) AS new_rank
FROM tbl_rank A, (SELECT MAX(rank) AS rank FROM tbl_rank) AS B
ORDER BY new_rank DESC;
```